Angular isn't loading the image stored in the database as a byte array
I'm working on a university project with an ASP.NET backend and an Angular frontend. This is my first Angular project ever, and I have a problem I can't solve. I'm storing images in the database as byte arrays.
This is the image to byte array conversion method:
byte[] ImageToByteArray(string fileName) 
{
    string workingDirectoy = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(workingDirectoy + "/Assets/" + fileName + ".jpg");
    Image img = Image.Load(fullPath);
    using (var ms  = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
        img.SaveAsPbm(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

This method successfully converts the images, and I can save those values as rows in my database. The rows show up.
I have a videogame Angular component which is used to store and display the values:
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-videogame',
  templateUrl: './videogame.component.html',
  styleUrl: './videogame.component.css'
})
export class VideogameComponent {
  @Input({ required: true })
  id: string;

  @Input({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Input({ required: true })
  date: string;

  @Input({ required: true })
  studioName: string;

  @Input({ required: true })
  rateing: string;

  @Input()
  image: Uint8Array;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){ }


  createImageUrlFromByteArray(): SafeUrl {
    let objectURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.image;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
  }
}


And this is the html for this component:
<div>
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  <p>{{date}}</p>
  <p>{{studioName}}</p>
  <p>{{rateing}}</p>
  <img [src]="createImageUrlFromByteArray()"/>
</div>


I believe these are the code sections responsible for image conversion and display, but I can provide more code if necessary. It's worth mentioning that fetching is successful; however, it occurs in a different component. I can log out the received data, and it matches what is stored in the database. I attempted to save the URL to a variable and bind the image source to that, but I'm encountering the same result. I'm not receiving any errors; the image simply isn't appearing on the page, instead, there's a small stock image icon.
Thanks for any help!

While checking my question, I found the bug. I saved the image as a PBM, while my images were saved in JPEG format...

You should probably just return File since it's already there... no need to convert to bytes.  Just set the src to the endpoint and return File... something like  try
{
using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open))
{
await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
}
memory.Position = 0;
         return File(memory, "image/jpg", shortPath);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine("Exception opening file: ", e.Message);
return NotFound();
}

Thank you for your reply. Fortunately, I found the problem, and after correcting the memory stream saving from PBM to JPEG, it works as intended.I want to be able to create new data in the database without directly saving the images so thats why im not loading the files directly.

you can still return a File (it's just the bytes with a mimetype and optional filename... it'll take bytestream, memorystream, filestream, etc...) to avoid the base64 stuff which will blow up the size a bit.
